# PYTHON2 - Is there ways to declare encoding method in csv write

Tags: python-2.7, csv, encoding

When I try to write cursor result coming from database execution (type is a list) to the csv, the error throws 
**a.writerow(lst) TypeError: write() argument 1 must be unicode, not str**

This is for python2. I've tried in python3 like the script below. But the system requirement asks me to change Python2.

This is the correct script using python3.

```
    results_percent = cursor.fetchall()
    with open(file4,'w',encoding="utf-8",newline='') as fp:
        a = csv.writer(fp, delimiter=',')
        a.writerow(['MFIName','ClientCountAtSignUp','UploadCountLastMonth','UploadCount','80%','Status'])
        a.writerows(results_percent)
```

The below is by using python2 which gives me error **a.writerow(lst) TypeError: write() argument 1 must be unicode, not str**

```
   results_percent = cursor.fetchall()
   with io.open(file4,'w',encoding='utf-8') as fp:
       a = csv.writer(fp, delimiter=',')
       lst = ['MFIName','ClientCountAtSignUp','UploadCountLastMonth','UploadCount','80%','Status']
       a.writerow(lst)
       a.writerows(results_percent)
```

The output is to write results_percent to csv file.

Comment: Have you looked at the [csv examples for Python_2](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html#csv-examples)?

Comment: yes. I already done. I think my problem is not csv. The type of data coming from database is pyodbc.Row. 
I still can't figured out how should i make to write in csv